# Convergence of stopping time to that of standard Wiener process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I ran into the following problem in one of my applied work and would appreciate if someone could kindly shed some lights.

**Settings**: Let $\{X_n\}$ be a sequence of cadlag processes in the Skorohod space $D[0,1]$ (I could take the stronger assumption that $X_n$ lies in $C[0,1]$, the space of all continuous functions, if needed). We assume that $X_n$ converges in distribution to the Wiener process,
$$
X_n \stackrel{d}{\longrightarrow} W
$$
Now fix constants $0 \leq l \leq u \leq 1$ and $c > 0$. Define a sequence of stopping times $\tau_n$ by
$$
\tau_n = \inf\{ l \leq t \leq u : X_n(t) > c \} \wedge u
$$
where $a \wedge b = \min(a, b)$. In other words, $\tau_n$ is the first moment, if exists, when the process $X_n$ moves above a threshold $c$, and equal to $u$ otherwise.

**Question**:

1. Does $X_n(\tau_n)$ converge in distribution?
2. If it converges in distribution, is it possible to derive the
       closed-form of the cumulative distribution function of the limit?

**My guess**: I conjecture that $X_n(\tau_n) \stackrel{d}{\longrightarrow} W(\tau)$, where
$$
\tau = \inf \{ l \leq t \leq u: W(t) > c \} \wedge u
$$
To this end, I have attempted to show $\tau_n$ converges in probability to $\tau$. Were this established, $(X_n, \tau_n)$ would converge in distribution to $(W, \tau)$, and continuous mapping theorem would entail the desired convergence. I couldn't figure it out, however.

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think the Skorohod representation theorem might help; it says you can find another sequence of processes $Y_n$, each having the same distribution as the corresponding $X_n$, with $Y_n$ converging *almost surely* to a Wiener process.  Then it seems you just have to show that if a sequence of paths converges in Skorohod topology, their values at the appropriate stopping times likewise converge.  It should be even easier in uniform topology.

Comment: The limit in distribution seems like it must just be the corresponding stopped Brownian motion, and the distribution of that must be known pretty well.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks much for the suggestion. I have actually considered the use of Skorohod representation theorem to convert the limit problem into an almost sure one. As you suggest, I could take advantage of continuity of the limit and work on the local uniform metric directly. But it appears to me that in general the sequence of stopping times need *not* converge to the corresponding one of the limit process.

Comment: @NateEldredge I actually imagined that a limit process which attains but not exceeds $c$ on the interval $(l, u)$, and then it seems that we could modify the sequence around the point $\tau$ where the limit achieves $c$ to keep $\liminf \tau_n > \tau$. In this case, it doesn't seem to me that $X_n(\tau_n)$ would converge to $W(\tau)$.. Perhaps the assumptions I impose on $X_n$ are too weak, or perhaps I should utilize some properties stronger than continuity of the Wiener process, which I have had no clue..

Comment: And yes, you are right: If the limit is Wiener process, it seems that I could make use of the Markov property to determine the c.d.f.

Comment: Crossposted to MathOverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/297233/convergence-of-sequence-of-stopped-partial-sums-to-functional-of-wiener-process

Comment: About crossposting: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16288/asking-the-same-question-on-mse-and-mo/25128#25128.  It's generally discouraged, so please avoid it in the future.

Comment: @NateEldredge I see, sorry for the inappropriate action. I shall be more considerate in the future. Anyway, thanks for your suggestion and help!